# Dynamically adding multiple log file URLs inside a classic email template for a Salesforce Object in Salesforce

Tags: apex, email, visual-workflow, email-template

We have to have  multiple URLs from a log file inserted dynamically into the following Web Intelligence  classic email template for the Task object. For example here is the mockup for the email template and you can see  a couple  of these:   in the template. Within the log file there could be multiple URLs included, if the person visited multiple pages. Is it possible that we complete this task using flows?  Thanks.

> ======= EMAIL TEMPLATE

Subject:  A Customer from  Visited Our Website

Body Copy:  Dear ,

Using Marketing’s Intelligence tool, we can see that someone from your customer account, , visited our website.

While on our website, this person visited the following pages:

·       **insert URL from log file**

·       **insert URL from log file**

> =========END EMAIL TEMPLATE

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved this:

> I will add a new custom field on task object instead of using the task's Description field . I have some AWS integrations that we already use that write to the task record which I use for updating the Email merge fields. So, I will see what happens with that.

> **Note**: If I didn't have those integrations, and was using Salesforce
> automation instead, then I would try this:

Dynamically adding multiple URLs from a log (CSV) file to a classic email template for a Salesforce Task is possible using a combination of flows and Apex.

> References:

1. Salesforce Flow: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow.htm&language=en_US&type=5
2. Apex Class: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm
3. Text Template with Merge Fields: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.anywhere_add_template_data_mention.htm&language=en_US&type=5

> Use a Text Template for the Email Body:

```
   In the Task's Description field, use merge fields to reference the dynamically 

    generated URLs from the Apex class:
```

Thanks to Ravi Shukla for giving me some hints.